# How to maximize heat dissipation on Peltier tiles

Tags: heatsink, peltier, cooling

I am not an electrical engineer by any stretch of the imagination, but I do like to tinker.

I am building a liquid cooling ramp (also known as an ice luge) liquid gets poured into the top of the channel at room temp and exits the bottom cold.  Right now the best that I can accomplish is a 20-degree difference in temperature. 72-degree liquid exits the bottom at 52 degrees.

I am doing this by using a 12v 17a power source connected to 6 Peltier tiles (12v 6a), a water pump, 2 fans, and a LED light for cool factor. I am using water as the liquid inside the cooling system. so an aluminum c channel on top of Peltier tiles, on top of aluminum cooling blocks, connected to tubing that runs water through a two fan PC radiator and back to the cooling blocks. All electrical is being run in parallel.

1. I would like to make the system as efficient as possible, are Peltier tiles even the best way to go? (I'm stuck with them for now, but I am open to suggestions for the 2.0 version)
2. after 30-60 mins of use, the water that is supposed to be cooled by the radiator, the water is borderline HOT and the cooling capability of the tiles is gone. This tells me that I need more radiator power, but I'm short on space/weight.  I don't want to hook up 6 radiator/fan combos if possible. Is there a more effective cooling method that anyone knows of?
3. My power supply is getting pretty warm.  I THINK that's OK, but have concerns about long term durability. The wires themselves are getting pretty warm also. I'm a little worried about a fire if left on over night.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Compressors are several times more efficient but also even heavier. You can slightly boost efficiency by splitting the load across more TECs run at a lower current and by cooling them better. I would try that first.

Comment: Also an easy and low weight solution to improve heat extraction is to use more powerful fans.

Comment: @user1850479 I don't know much about compressors, but I will do my research. Thank you for the suggestion.  By adding more Peltier tiles, wouldn't that boost up the necessary amperage quite a bit? I already feel like I'm pushing this baby as hard as I can.  I can of course get a beefier power source, but I am finding that the higher the amperage, the higher the cost.

Comment: Run the cooling water through a bong/swamp/evaporative cooler, will keep it cooler than a  small radiator. A compressor system would be several times better COP than Peltiers. You can improve Peltier COP by running more of them at a lower power.

Comment: Better fans should help, as would better radiators, like maybe pin-fin heatsinks (which have lots of surface area and a flat top where you can mount the fans.)

Comment: Add a thermal isolation at all outside surfaces of the aluminum to avoid losses there.

Comment: Would simply adding more powerful fans to the existing radiator do much good?  I read somewhere that it isn't very effective, but that logic doesn't make any sense to me.  If I blow on my pizza harder it gets colder faster, ya know?

Comment: @Jens, do you mean a thermal insulation gasket like this?

https://www.mpja.com/40mm-x-40mm-Foam-Insulator-for-Peltier-Modules/productinfo/33912%20IN/

I was thinking of using a thermal caulk of sorts on the sides to transfer the cold to the sides of the c channel

Comment: @Jens OH! You mean on the outside of the aluminum c channel.  that is a pretty good idea.  Maybe some sort of spray-on insulation will be effective and still esthetically pleasing.

Comment: I used ArmaFlex as isolator but in your case it could spoil the aesthetics

Comment: You can improve efficiency by splitting the same load across more units such that each uses less current. Running a TEC at it's maximum rated current results in very high heat and lower efficiency. You didn't explain what current you're driving through each one, but from context I'm going to guess you're driving them too hard. Do you have a spec sheet?

Comment: So, what are these "degrees" you mention here? 72°C is close to boiling hot, so this seems to be fine... Some ancient or local unit like °Ra, °F, °Re ?

Comment: TEC1-12706:
Voltage: 12V
Umax (V): 15V
Cooling power: Qcmax 58-65W
Imax (A): 5.8A
Tmax(Qc=0): up to 65°C
Operates Temperature: -30°C to 83°C

Water Pump:
Rated voltage: DC12V
Working current: 920Ma±15%
Power: 19W±15%

I don't have specs on the two fans on the radiator, but they are 12v also, assuming low amperage.

All connected to the 12v 17a power supply.  I just twisted all of the wires together and put a butt connector on the end then wired them to the power supply.

Comment: Sorry, I was saying 72F, average room temp.  Google says that is 22.22 degrees Celcius.

Comment: _All_ TEM surfaces should be in good contact with thermal conductor. If not, it will waste power or overheat and degrade. Water pipes can be thinner twice without power deterioration. Consider using car heater radiator, it is bigger, inexpensive and effective. It can be paired with axial fan also. At my rough non-experienced estimation, 10-12 TEMs are needed. Consider using side panels as aluminum radiators. Then, thermal insulation of cold groove is adviced or just horizontal screen to block hot air.

Comment: @vladimir So if I am understanding you correctly, use 10-12 TECS instead of the 6 I have running currently? I am concerned about power if I added more TECs.  Wouldnt that increase my power draw?  I would love to find TECs that are only 1" wide to avoid having them be wider then my c channel and wasting energy as you had pointed out. 
 The best solution that I can find is the thermal caulk idea to try to transfer some of that coolness up to the c channel.

Comment: @vladimir Waterpipes can be thinner twice? My water pipes start at 12mm, then step down to 10mm at the first junction, then steps down to 9mm at the next junction.  Since the water is splitting from one to two pipes at each junction, I thought it would be smart to make them smaller each time they split. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: @vladimir Im not sure what you are referring to when you suggest using side panels as aluminum radiators, do you mean the side panels of the actual unit that I currently have constructed out of wood? It wouldn't be a bad idea to use the actual structure of the unit to disperse heat.  Lastly, cold groove thermal insulation? horizontal screen? Like a metal screen from home depot? What would that do? Where would I mount said screen horizontally?

Comment: @user1850479 I added the best version of a spec sheet that I could above.  I'm still not understanding how I can add more TECs.  Everytime I add more, it just increases the amp requirements, correct? Iv I exceed the max amperage output of the power source, will it just cap out and in turn reduce the voltage as well? What would that do to the other components that are using 12v?

Comment: I think those specs are probably copy and pasted from a couple unrelated products, so not much use.  I guess this was a particularly sketchy seller?  You should probably measure the current and see how hard you're loading (or overloading) your power supply.  Since a TEC is essentially a resistor, you can set the current to whatever you want by changing the voltage.

Comment: With these TECs you can add aluminum pads between them and cold groove. About pipe thickness, i saw only pipe connected to Peltier pads, it looks too thick, typically, 4 mm should be enough if pump works fine. Overheating shows that it needs more heat exchange area. If you are limited in space, then side panels can be used for this. Then they will get warm, then hot air, going up from them, will heat the cold groove, so you will need screen against hot air from below. From cloth, paper, anything. TEMs are limited in temp. difference, so, the colder is cooling water, the colder is target.